# socket.io 1.0.x not compatible with require.js?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, requirejs

Any time I try to load socket.io 1.0.x after require.js, it produces

> Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.10/require.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var socket = io('http://localhost');
</script>
```

But if I put socket.io before require.js, it doesn't produce any error:

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.6.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.10/require.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var socket = io('http://localhost');
</script>
```

This of course means that socket.io cannot be loaded by require.js this way:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: { 

        'socketio' : ['https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.6'],


    },
    shim: {

        'socketio': {
            exports: 'io'
        }
    }
});

require(['socketio'], function(io){

    console.log(window.io); //undefined


})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Socket.io 0.x

with socket.io 0.x you needed in to export io in the require.js config:

```
shim: {   
  'socket.io-client': {    
     exports: 'io'    
   } 
}
```

and your js file:

```
define(['socket.io-client'], function () {
  // io is exported here    

  var socket = io.connect ...
}
```

### Socket.io 1.x

with socket.io 1.x, no need to export io in the require.js config file

and your js file:

```
define(['socket.io-client'], function (io) {
  // io an argument of the function   

  var socket = io.connect ...
}
```

**But in both cases, you have to use the io object in the define so that it is loaded correctly by require.js when you need it.**

Also note that you need **socket.io-client** instead of **socket.io** in the browser

Answer (score 0):

RequireJS creates a `require` and `define` set of methods... the socket.io js file sees this, and defines itself.

*Include socket.io first* ***or*** *Use AMD*

Answer (score 0):

I specifically wanted the bower packages ([ng-socket](https://github.com/chrisenytc/ng-socket)), and [socket.io-client](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client) to cooperate via RequireJS. At first ng-socket errored because `io` was undefined, even with shimmed deps.

So, I added a `startSocketIo.js` file:

```
define([
  'socket.io-client'],function(io) {
  window.io = io;
});
```

and added a deps section to the root of my require config file:

```
deps: [
  './startSocketIo'
],
```

I see this as analogous to adding via a script tag and no better for performance, but it allowed me to keep using unmodified bower packages and using requirejs for all my js.